# There are multiple mobx instances actives

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

Since the last update of Mobx 3.6 to Mobx 4, my application just stopped working. I'm using react-native and I just followed the instructions to migrate to the newest features, but my application just keeps crashing displaying the following error:

> [mobx] There are multiple mobx instances active. This might lead to unexpected results: See https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1082 for details.

[Click here to check the error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LVK6.png)

#### Mobx store:

I just created a simple observable object, with the following code:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { observable } from "mobx";

const ProductsStore = observable.object(
  {
    selectedProduct: null,
    products: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "NVIDIA 1050TI",
        desc: "4GB OC",
        model: "ASUS",
        price: 1050,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "NVIDIA 1060TI",
        desc: "6GB OC",
        model: "EVGA",
        price: 1050,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "NVIDIA 1070TI",
        desc: "8GB OC",
        model: "MSI",
        price: 1050,
        quantity: 1
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "NVIDIA 1080TI",
        desc: "11GB OC",
        model: "FOUNDERS EDITION",
        price: 1050,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  { selectedProduct: observable, products: observable }
);

export { ProductsStore };
```

But, when I try to import this file, it will crash the application and it will display the error that I've mentioned before.

```
import { ProductsStore } from '@store'
```

I've tried without the alias, but it seems it's not working.

Comment: Quick note: I've tried to add as peerDependencies and even in devDependencies, not in dependencies. Then, reinstalled the packages and the error persists.

Comment: This is a project setup issue, so posting mobx code isn't gonna help. Check if mobx is only once in your node_modules `tree -d | grep mobx` to quickly check. If it is unique, you might have linked packages into your project that also contain mobx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved the problem while chatting with @mweststrate and figured out that in my project, I'm using a library which depends from an old version of mobx.

Versions > 3.6, only accepts one instance of mobx.

The library `react-native-router-flux` is using a old version, which was responsible for causing this issue.

The workaround, was adding the `resolutions` property to the `package.json` file and adding the `mobx` and `mobx-react` to this property.

```
  "resolutions": {
    "mobx": "^4.1.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.0.0"
  },
```

But the `resolutions` property, is **only available** for `yarn`, **not for** `npm`. This property, overwrites old referred dependencies. For further questions, read the docs.

[Selective resolutions in yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/)

[Multiple MobX instances in your application #1082](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1082#issuecomment-352409804)

Comment: My version is 5.0.3 and I have the error coming up in my console every so often. I think it may have something to do with the fact that I use Server-Side-Rendering(Next.js).